# What JS framework offers scroll functionality (+animation) in a div without a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, user-interface, scroll

All: I want to scroll through a sequence of tumblr/twitter posts as a long sequence of texts.

Let's say we have:

```
<div id="mainContent">
     _some content_
</div>
```

where the css for mainContent is:

```
#mainContent {
    padding: 20px 20px; 
    background: #FFF;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I really like the functionality of [Scrollable jQuery](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html), but they require pagination and an array of elements.

I'm looking for tips in any of these categories:

- a js framework I can use to achieve this
- a solution to paginating the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution through [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/animation/scroll.html).